# When ever compiling pjsip latest version 2.4.5 for G729 codec in ios getting error

Tags: ios, iphone, pjsip

Here compiling steps and logs

> Johns-Mac-mini:pjproject-2.4.5 ios-dev$ ./configure-iphone
>   --enable-g729-codec
>
> Johns-Mac-mini:pjproject-2.4.5 ios-dev$ make dep && make clean && make

Finally got this error.

> /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/../../../Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool
>   -static -o  ../../lib/libg7221codec-armv7-apple-darwin_ios.a  output/libg7221codec-armv7-apple-darwin_ios/common/common.o 
>   output/libg7221codec-armv7-apple-darwin_ios/common/huff_tab.o 
>   output/libg7221codec-armv7-apple-darwin_ios/common/tables.o 
>   output/libg7221codec-armv7-apple-darwin_ios/common/basic_op.o 
>   output/libg7221codec-armv7-apple-darwin_ios/decode/coef2sam.o 
>   output/libg7221codec-armv7-apple-darwin_ios/decode/dct4_s.o 
>   output/libg7221codec-armv7-apple-darwin_ios/decode/decoder.o 
>   output/libg7221codec-armv7-apple-darwin_ios/encode/dct4_a.o 
>   output/libg7221codec-armv7-apple-darwin_ios/encode/sam2coef.o 
>   output/libg7221codec-armv7-apple-darwin_ios/encode/encoder.o echo
>   ranlib ../../lib/libg7221codec-armv7-apple-darwin_ios.a ranlib
>   ../../lib/libg7221codec-armv7-apple-darwin_ios.a
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f
>   /Projects/WesternUnion/SourceCode/pjproject-2.4.5/build/rules.mak
>   APP=G729_CODEC app=libg729codec
>   ../../lib/libg729codec-armv7-apple-darwin_ios.a
>
> make[3]: *** No rule to make target
>   `../../lib/libg729codec-armv7-apple-darwin_ios.a'.  Stop. make[2]: ***
>   [libg729codec] Error 2
>
> make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
>
> make: *** [all] Error 1

Any help or suggestion would be appreciable.

Comment: The option enable-g729-codec is not a valid option in the base distribution. Where did you get the instructions to add that option?

Comment: i am following this link

http://trac.etellicom.com/wiki/G729CodecForPJSIP2x_iOS6

Comment: Then it's non standard instructions - I suggest you clarify that in the question. Perhaps people who have followed that instructions before can answer.

Comment: If you know any perfect instructions for compiling. Please tell me any suggestion would be appreciable.